# Trouble making background image for a div auto-resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been wresting with this for a couple of hours now and am not making progress. Thought I would come here for help.   My task is simple and common.  Using BS3, I am trying to have a full page container have a background image which will resize when you resize the browser.  Seems simple enough but the few solutions I've found on here simply don't work.  Here's where I'm at:

```
<section id="LandingRow">
<div class="LandingRowWrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <%--Visible in small, med, large devices.--%>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 hidden-xs">
                <div class="row">
                ...content...
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                ...content...
                </div>
            </div>


            <%--Visible in xs devices only.--%>
            <div class="col-sm-12 visible-xs">
            ...content...
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...and my css....

```
.LandingRowWrapper 
{
    border-width: 1px; 
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-color: #bbd8e7;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url('../images/slider3.jpg');
}
```

Much appreciated!!

Comment: Is that what you're trying to do is have your image cover the background on all size devices?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the background to cover both the height and width of the container, I would use `background-size: cover;`. If you want it to just scale horizontally and keep the height proportionate `background-size: 100;%` should do the trick.